# How do I put a text field inside a multicolumn cell?

Tags: multicolumn

New to LaTeX and new user on the forum; let me know if there's something I can do to improve my question.

I'm creating a fillable PDF and can't figure out how to put a text field inside a multicolumn cell.

(I have other 4-column rows above and below the rows I'm showing here, and omitted them for simplicity's sake in showing the issue I'm having. I do need 4 columns.)

This is what I've got so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline

\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf {Accountant}}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|} {Name} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|} {E-mail}

\multicolumn{2}{l} {\TextField[width=5em,bordercolor=black,name=UE]{ }} & \multicolumn{2}{l} {\TextField[width=5em,bordercolor=black,name=UE]{ }} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

When I compile, I get the following error: ! Misplaced \omit.\multispan ->\omit \@multispan

I've read many pages looking for a solution and haven't found anything specific to this issue yet. Many thanks

Comment: After `\multicolumn{2}{|l|} {Name} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|} {E-mail}
` you need double backslash.

Comment: why you define four columns if you actually the use only two (by use of `\multicolumn{2}{l}{...}`)? I

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{Form}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  \hline
   row & col & col \\
  \hline
   row & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}|}{\TextField[bordercolor=red, borderwidth=1]{}} \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer. otherwise this is considered "not helpful"